# Simplifying "a == True:" to "a" - is it a good idea?

Tags: python, pep8

PEP8 suggests the following code should be simplified.

The original

```
if a == True:
```

The suggestion

```
if a:
```

However, these two are not the same. I figured out when I followed the PEP8 recommendation. Try with the following code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.nan

if a == True:
    print('a is True')
else:
    print('a is not True')
    
if a:
    print('a is True')
else:
    print('a is not True')
```

And you will figure out that the first tells a is not true (correctly) while the second one incorrectly tells a is true.

```
a is not True
a is True
```

What is the point of this misleading suggestion?

Comment: If you're working with a variable whose possible values are `True` or `np.nan`, then there's your design problem, not the Boolean comparison. An `if` statement checks truthiness of your data. You should always know the general shape of your data. If the data is a list, `if` checks that it's empty. If the data is a Boolean, `if` checks that it's true. Python programmers are able to read these intentions at a glance. An `== True` just obfuscates that and makes idiomatic Python coders think something extremely fishy is going on.

Comment: Your problem here is a type mismatch. Is `a` a boolean or a number? You assign `nan` to it, which has a truthiness value. When you say `a = np.nan; if a` you're saying 'does a have a value'. (It does, a value of nan.) Generally, if a value is assigned to a name that is not explicitly False, None, 0 or empty you can expect the truth evaluation to treat it as 'True'. Moreover, though, since you don't assign `a = True` when you ask `if a == True` you'll get false. Same as if you asked `if 2 == True`. `nan` is not True - it's not even a boolean.

Comment: The PEP8 suggestions fundamentally assumes you understand Python's truth value testing semantics, [here is the relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) In this case, `np.nan` *is truthy*. Why did *you think otherwise*?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good feedback.

Still I think it is a bit problematic to suggest simplifying a phrase with something that doesn't give the same result.

Comment: Matti: The very [definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/truthiness) of "truthiness" indicates that the quality of seeming to be true is without regard to logic, factual evidence, or the like.

Comment: @MattiHonkanen That's why it's a style warning, not a compiler error. PEP8 suggestions are meant to be guides, not absolute truths. There are situations where `== True` makes sense (personally, I've used that in the past when parsing JSON, where `True` serves the dual purpose of "Python Boolean value" and "JSON literal"). But, in 90% of cases, `== True` is extraneous and only serves to confuse.

Answer (score 6):

You are misreading the PEP8 style guide. Here is the relevant part (emphasis mine):

> Don't compare **boolean** values to True or False using ==:
>
> ```py
> # Correct:
> if greeting:
> # Wrong:
> if greeting == True:
> ```

Since `np.nan` is not a boolean value, this advice does not apply.

Note that if you are comparing a numeric value to `True`, then you are normally doing something wrong in the first place. The numeric values `1` and `1.0` are both equal to `True`, so if you have a variable which could be either numeric or boolean, this test may give you unexpected results. It is also generally an anti-pattern to have a variable which could be either a boolean or something other than a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `np.nan` is works the same way as `float('nan')`.

```
import numpy as np
print(type(np.nan))  # <class 'float'>
```

Python normally [says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> By default, an object is considered **true** unless its class defines
> either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method
> that returns zero, when called with the object.

Then for built-in numeric types, it says any zeros are considered `False`:

> zero of any numeric type: 0, **0.0**, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)

As I bolded the only float type which is False, any other float numbers are considered `True`.

so :

```
print(bool(float('nan')))   # True
```

Numpy also acts like how python does.

When you say `if obj:` python tries to get the truth value of the `obj` by the help of `bool()` which indeed looks at `__bool__` and `__len__` special methods. (`__bool__` has higher priority if implemented).

Comment: "np.nan is somehow works the same way as float('nan')" Of course, since `np.nan` *is the same type of object with the same type of value as `float('nan')`.

Comment: "When you say `if obj:` it turns into `if bool(obj) is True:` No, python does that. Numpy has no control over that behavior. Actually, the primary numpy type, `np.ndarray`, *throws an error*. because `numpy.ndarray.__bool__` raises an error (unless you are working with a numpy.ndarray with one element, confusingly)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, in both cases it throws a ValueError , I mean (`if arr:`) and `bool(arr)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So isn't it because `if arr:` tries to call `bool()` on `arr` ?

Comment: It is because of that. Let me be precise, the mechanics of how a conditional statement, e.g. `if something:` are handled is part of the interpreter runtime, the language itself.  Essentially, `bool(something)` and `len(something)` are used, and objects can decide how to respond to it using the special method hooks, `__bool__` and `__len__` I'm not disagreeing with your answer, just suggesting a way to rephrase to make it more clear.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. Rephrased.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the explicit conditional. The second option will always give you True if a!=0, besides, that type of conditionals are confusing when you didn't write the code.

Answer (score -1):

This means that the variable `a` has a value equal to `True` or not.

```
if a == True:
```

But does this variable `a` have a value or not.

```
if a:
```